# Synonym for "issues arose"

Tags: word-choice, expressions

What is another way to say "Issues arose", as in "Some issues arose during the testing phase of the project."

Comment: Why don't you like "issues arose"?

Comment: "problems/topics/questions emerged" ?

Comment: @Graham Nicol, I didn't like "arose" because it didn't seem like an approriate verb for a technical business document.

Comment: @Graffito, thank you for your suggestion. I especially like the verb "emerged".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This depends on whether you want to mention the subject or not, as you original sentence uses passive voice. But if you discovered some problems during testing you could say:

1. "We **ran into some problems** during the testing phase of the project."
2. "We **encountered some problems** during the testing phase of the project."

Here's a real-world example:

> The delivery of the Voice Recognition System for external use by members of the public had **encountered some problems during the testing phase** but would go live shortly.

http://cds.bromley.gov.uk/ieListDocuments.aspx?MId=1692

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I was trying to use the passive voice because I was writing to a client and trying not to place the blame on a specific group. However, your suggestion was helpful.

Comment: Glad I could help, Karen.

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

"Some problems **cropped up** during the testing process."

> crop up: to appear unexpectedly or occasionally.

[**American Heritage Dictionary**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Crop+up)

Answer (score -1):

"Stumbling blocks" and "Problems" are two that pop into my mind.